# Earliest support of __alignof__ in GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, memory-alignment

I need a portable way to determine alignment requirements of a structure, where portability includes legacy versions of GCC. Parts of project are stuck with embedded platforms supporting pre-C++11 standard only, as early as GCC v.3.6.

There is a non-ISO `__alignof__` (a macro? a function?) analog of C++11 operator `alignof` which I can use, but what is the earliest version of GCC compiler would support it? Were there alternatives or changes in naming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The oldest version of GCC with documentation available online at gcc.gnu.org is 2.95.3. That version [does support](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/gcc_4.html#SEC89) `__alignof__` extension.